# Remove method in ArrayList

Tags: java

```
public void remove(Object o) {
    remove(size, o);
}

public void remove(int index, Object o) {
    for (int i=index; i<size-1; i++) 
        data[i] = data[i - 1];

    data[index] = o;
    size--;
}
```

I want to remove certain elements using index or object, but now it only remove the last element. Can I know how to fix this thing?

Comment: *how to fix this thing?* - as your title suggests, use an ArrayList

Comment: @AxelH would work if he was using an ArrayList

Comment: Your code does not look right. It's not complete. Please provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AxelH more like a remove first and then shift all to front + add

Comment: and what is that data? It looks like you are removing from an array and not an arraylist

Comment: 1. it is not removing the last element  2. the logic does not make sense.  It is replacing everything after `index` to data[index],  3. it is replacing `data[index]` with input object which, again, makes no sense

Comment: If you're trying to remove an object, why does your method have `data[index] = o;` ?

Comment: @AxelH exactly. This method is like the worst possible API Interface that can be declared. Name it remove, but it replaces, shifts, and adds ;)

Comment: Don't forget to check "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)"

Answer (score 1):

Your method doesn't remove at all.

Using : (not java code)

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  
data.remove(3, 99) // 3 is the index, not the value.
```

First, the loop shift every on the right (start one cell before the index).

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Losing the last value (hidden by the `size`variable), it is actually at `data[size]`

Then it set `Object o` at the index.

```
[0, 1, 2, 99, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

And decrements the size, losing another value.

```
[0, 1, 2, 99, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Where the result should be

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  
data.remove(3); //the index, not the value but in this example, the value is the same as the index
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

It is a mix of `add` and `remove` methods badly implemented on the index.

---

To remove an element from an array, you only need to shift every item after the index on the left. I also change the return value to match [`List.remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) by return the value removed. (You could/should `implements List<T>` to get a correct `Collection`)

```
private T remove(int index){
    //keep the value to return at the end        
    T t = data[index];

    //Shift from index to the end
    for(int i = index; i < size - 1; ++i){
        data[index] = data[index + 1];
    }

    //remove the reference for an eventual GC visibility (prevent memory leaks)
    data[size - 1] = null;
    size--;

    return t;
}
```

Set `null` on the last cell to be sure to release the reference for the GC.
And of course, decrement the size.

This is not safe to use, this requires some bounds verifications ! This could throw a [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) for the moment

Answer (score -3):

Your Code does not remove any items from your list. 
If you want to remove something use the methods that are already provided:
list.remove(index) or list.remove(Object)

Comment: If it was using an actual `List` implementation, but it is not. He is implementing it, for learning purpose I would guess.